# Three js Texture Loader can't load a texture

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, three.js, textures, loader

I'm trying to load an image with three js (I want the same result as this project : https://github.com/brunoimbrizi/interactive-particles).
But when I run the project, the code don't want to load the image and display directly an error.
Here is my code :

```
init(src) {
        const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

        loader.load('images/sample-01.png',
            (texture) => {
                console.log('YOOOO');
                this.texture = texture;
                this.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
                this.texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
                this.texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

                this.width = texture.image.width;
                this.height = texture.image.height;

                this.initPoints(true);
                this.initHitArea();
                this.initTouch();
                this.resize();
                this.show();
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log('LOADING');
            },

            // onError callback
            function (err) {
                console.error('An error happened.', err);
            });
    }
```

I'm convinced that the image path is right, so I have any idea of the problem unfortunately.
Here is the error :

[image: ERROR HERE]

I'm running this project on Vue js, with npm run dev so I'm on a server.

I hope someone will be able to help me, I'm working on this for 3 days ...

Thank you !

Comment: What does your Network tab show you? Is the `sample-01.png` image being loaded, or is it showing a 404 error under the "Status" column?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the loaded texture without any peripheral method calls. Something simple as this:

```js
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texMap = loader.load('images/sample-01.png');

new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texMap});
```

I'm pretty certain that if the image URL is correct, and the simple test above works, then the problem is coming from one of these extra methods:

```
this.initPoints(true);
this.initHitArea();
this.initTouch();
this.resize();
this.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tryed to load the texture in a simple way, but it looks like it doesn't work too. When I console.log the mesh material map, image is stated as undifined, and the texture path don't appear.. It seems to be the same error :(

Comment: @DavyJacquemaard Did you check your Network tab to see if the image is loading at all?

Comment: Yes the image is in the network tab, no error 404 !

Comment: Then I don't know what else it could be. If you could show a working example via [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or JSFiddle then it would be easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yes I tried to make a JSFiddle (I'm not at ease with that) but this is a complex VueJS project with a lot of modules so I have just put the main methods in the Javascript part. Of course the example dosn't work so I don't think it gonna help you to help me. But why not, there is maybe a huge code error : https://jsfiddle.net/davy_j11/r8vepkjd/

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to load an image with three js inside react component and I got the same error.

For me, replace path in load method by require(path) works fine. For this example it would give :

```js
  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  const texMap = loader.load(require('../images/sample-01.png'));
    
  new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texMap});
```